# Remove part of a datetime index in a pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, numpy-ndarray, datetime-format

I wanted to remove the year and minute part of the date-values in the index of a pandas df:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-05-16 14:31:14', '2022-05-16 16:31:15',
               '2022-05-16 18:31:16', '2022-05-16 20:31:17',
               '2022-05-16 22:31:18', '2022-05-17 00:31:19',
               '2022-05-17 02:31:20', '2022-05-17 04:31:21',
               '2022-05-17 06:31:22', '2022-05-17 08:31:23',
               ...
               '2022-06-11 06:12:18', '2022-06-11 08:12:18',
               '2022-06-11 10:12:18', '2022-06-11 12:12:18',
               '2022-06-11 14:12:18', '2022-06-11 16:12:18',
               '2022-06-11 18:12:18', '2022-06-11 20:12:18',
               '2022-06-11 22:12:18', '2022-06-12 00:12:18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=0, length=320, freq=None)
```

the format that I want the values in the whole array to is '05-16 14', (month, day, hour)

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible **if you want to keep the datetime type**, you necessarily need to convert to string using `strftime`:

```
df.index.strftime('%m-%d %H')
```

output:

```
Index(['05-16 14', '05-16 16', '05-16 18', '05-16 20', '05-16 22', '05-17 00',
       '05-17 02', '05-17 04', '05-17 06', '05-17 08', '06-11 06', '06-11 08',
       '06-11 10', '06-11 12', '06-11 14', '06-11 16', '06-11 18', '06-11 20',
       '06-11 22', '06-12 00'],
      dtype='object')
```